# Use libpcap with a socket connection

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, freebsd

Is it possible to use libpcap to detect an incoming connection, and dynamically create a socket made to accept just that connection, or is it too late by the time libpcap sniffs the packet? I am asking because I only want to open the socket connection for a particular session, not for any old connection that comes across the wire. As such, I don't have a socket already bound and listening to an interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot simpler to open a listening socket and just close all incoming connections that weren't from the required peer. You can do all that without using libpcap at all.